# In graph theory what is a simple circuit?

Tags: graph-theory

In graph theory what is a simple circuit?

I have started studying trees and I'm confused on what exactly is a simple circuit.

I know a tree must be connected and have no simple circuits. Below I have drawn a graph and labeled the vertices to maybe help me better understand.

[graph with a simple circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opE1H.png)

Comment: bcdb is the simple circuit.

Comment: Ok, thank you I think this helped cleared up the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

A simple circuit is one of the sort $v_1, \dotsc, v_n, v_1$ where $v_i \neq v_j$ if $i\neq j.$ As pointed out in the comments, we also want $n>2$ above.

Comment: In an undirected graph you'll also want to have a condition that excludes "$v_1, v_2, v_1$".

Comment: @Troposphere good point, fixed.